# Flash - Full Screen Image fx

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fullscreen

I am wondering about the image effect seen on this site
http://www.daffys.com/

I'm referring to the dotted / grid-like effect on the images. Do you think it's a simple Photoshop treatment or is it an effect done in Flash, related to the fact that the images scale full screen. I've seen this on many other sites and would be very interested in your opinions, even better if someone has already done this and could point me in the right direction on how to get this done.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the as2 version:
http://flashden.net/item/true-full-screen-progressive-video-background-with-scan-lines/full_screen_preview/15071

I'm sure the is an as3 version of this floating around somewhere, or the code can be updated to as3

Comment: Thanks, this isn't what I was looking for but you definitely got me on the right track by giving me the name of the effect! Scan lines are a fairly popular effect, so now that I have the name, I can find a wealth of info out there! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is just a layer with the dots on top of another layer with the image.

Comment: thanks! 
what would be the point do you think? just a way to stop people from copying content without being too obvious about it and still retaining some design quality?...

Comment: Just for added texture for their design, nothing to do with copyrights imho

Answer (score 0):

1. Daffy's is a horrible website design. It took too long to load for no reason. If I were a potential customer, I would have fled in horror.
2. Dot-effect looks to be a semi-transparent layer on top of the images. The images move, but the dots don't, so that means it's in flash. Daffy's logo sits on top of the dots layer.
3. The site is horrible. Even after it's loaded. Sorry. Flash for no reason annoys me.

Comment: The question wasn't about Daffy's actually, only I've seen this effect a few times and was wondering about the idea behind it... Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: I actually love their site, loaded fast for me... Also great use of nice photography

Comment: +1. This is the kind of site, that supplies flash-opponents with rock solid arguments.